# Providing Evidence of residency for 3 of the last 5 years - Which are the last 5 years?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

today I was reading on the website this:

Providing Evidence of residency for 3 of the last 5 years

### In order to receive funding from SUSI, you must have been resident in the Irish State or the EU/EEA/Swiss Federation for three of the last five years.

Which 5 last years are meant? It never includes current year? 5 years before this current year? or 5 years including this one though it has just started? (what if I was in the middle of this year 2017, would it be included then? or no?)

So the LAST 5 YEARS are:

2017,2016,2015,2014,2013 or 2016,2015,2014,2013,2012??

We never cover the on-going year? just the calendar ones that have already passed or? And does that also apply to months/weeks? - by which I mean that only completed weeks/months are meant by last weeks/months, not the one that is current which is not over yet. Or am I wrong in understanding this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Instead of asking us and relying on our interpretation for financial support that you require why not just call them on the phone and ask them? I'm sure they would be more than happy to *tell* you, and then you'll know for sure.

Comment: Personally, I would assume they meant "five years prior to submitting the request", and essentially subtract five years from the current date. However, I agree with @mstorkson and [Andrew's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/117966/1639) that the right move is to contact the relevant authority and ask to be certain.

Comment: You should contact the organization using the information on their website: https://susi.ie/contact/ Native speakers have the same sort of questions when we read statements like these, so there is no way for us to tell you for certain what it means just based on the language.

Answer (score 1):

The laws of each jurisdiction are different, so without researching I could not say for sure.  If this is an important question for you, you **must** ask someone who works in the Irish government to be specific.

There is also a question of what it means to be "resident".  This can be very complicated but usually requires you to live in that place for a significant portion of the year, obtain local documentation (get a license, pay taxes, etc), or own property (and live in it).  I don't know what those laws are for Ireland, so you will have to research that as well.

Without further explanation I would assume that it means, going back five calendar years (not including the current year), you had to have been *resident* for at least three out of those five *calendar* years.  It may include the current year **if** it is late enough in the year that you can establish "residency" for this year.

Again, this is just a casual reading, and should not be taken as actual *advice*.  Please do the research and ask.

Answer (score 0):

The 1,825 days approaching this, the day you are authoring the question, is how I'd interpret it.

To do otherwise is to A: introduce a rounding error, and B: isn't scalable if you look at other terms.

Consider:

- "I've been alive for the past two millennia." I'm 40.
- "I've had this car for the past two centuries." It's a '99.
- "We've been dating for the past two years." We started in December.